# Storing how many url and url click for each sent email in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I would like to know if it is possible to store how many URL are they in each email sent and how many times each url has been clicked in Data Extension using maybe data view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part of your question, all needed data can be found in **Click** data view (vide [MC dev documentation about that view](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_click/)), which can be accessed using **Automation Studio** SQL activity, and product of that activity can be stored in Data Extension.

If you know `ID` of email, that you have sent (which can be obtained from tracking panel or from the content builder - viewing message details), you can use that information to join **Click** and **Job** data view, and group it by e-mail and URL. Adding to this some aggregate SQL functions can give you `SUM` of clicks in each link, per email.

But there is one **but**, in before-mentioned Data View you can find only links that have been clicked. I don't know any convenient programmatic approach to list all links from email (clicked and non-clicked).